# getData() missing image src attribute

Tags: reactjs, ckeditor, electron, ckeditor5

When I try to use editor.getData(), It`s return html code.

But if this code included an img tag, it will return me

```
<figure class="image"><img></figure>
```

Comment: Never seen that happen with standard configuration. Provide a demo that reproduces problem

Comment: src attribute will be removed by the browser if there's no value in it. Be sure to bind the path.